# Reading from a firebase database with android not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Whenever I try to read from this database it comes back null. you can see in the picture that it is not null in the database. I have look for good documentation on this but I don't believe it exist I just need it to return a string or int with value of 58 from dose so I can display it in my activity.

[image: Firebase database]

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    // ...
            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    // Read from the database
            mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                    // whenever data at this location is updated.
                    String Value = dataSnapshot.child(pName).child("dose").getValue(String.class);
                    count.setText(Value);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                    // Failed to read value

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because the data type of the 'dose' is Integer. Instead of converting to **String**, you need to use **Integer**.

```
String Value = dataSnapshot.child(pName).child("dose").getValue(Integer.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it is still returning null